# Flutter Build on Azure Pipelines

Tags: flutter, azure-pipelines

I am unable to build a Flutter app on Azure pipelines, even though it compiles on local machine.

The error presented is as below:

```
[+1222 ms] lib/services/sync/sync_service.dart:7:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/services/AppVersion/app_version_service.dart': No such file or directory
[        ] import 'package:columbus/services/AppVersion/app_version_service.dart';
[        ]        ^
[ +863 ms] lib/services/sync/sync_service.dart:55:10: Error: Type 'AppVersionService' not found.
[        ]   static AppVersionService _appVersionService;
[        ]          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+2934 ms] lib/services/sync/sync_service.dart:55:10: Error: 'AppVersionService' isn't a type.
[        ]   static AppVersionService _appVersionService;
[        ]          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +6 ms] lib/services/sync/sync_service.dart:88:26: Error: The method 'AppVersionService' isn't defined for the class 'SyncService'.
[        ]  - 'SyncService' is from 'package:columbus/services/sync/sync_service.dart' ('lib/services/sync/sync_service.dart').
[        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'AppVersionService'.
[        ]     _appVersionService = AppVersionService();
[        ]                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+8165 ms] killing pid 2546
[        ] test 1: cleaning up...
[        ] test 1: deleting temporary directory
[        ] test 1: waiting for controller sink to close
```

My pipeline is as follows:

The below is my pipeline. I have tried manually and using the Flutter Pipeline plugin. The error is the same for both. Any advice would be great.

I have deliberately left out the header parts of the Pipeline, cant post otherwise with a "mostly code" comment! :)

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true
  path: 'mobile_ui'
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 17
    jdkArchitectureOption: x64
    jdkSourceOption: PreInstalled
  displayName: 'Install Java 17 SDK'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'wget https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.3.6-stable.tar.xz'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'tar -xvf flutter_linux_3.3.6-stable.tar.xz'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'ls'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.prependpath]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/flutter/bin"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.prependpath]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Flutter Doctor"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: flutter doctor
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Restore Packages"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: flutter pub get
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: PowerShell@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'flutter test --verbose'
    errorActionPreference: 'continue'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
- task: FlutterInstall@0
  displayName: 'Install Flutter SDK'
  inputs:
    version: custom
    customVersion: 3.3.6
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Build Android Bundle'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    script: '$(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build appbundle --build-name=2022.11.1 --build-number=$(Build.BuildNumber) --flavor development -t lib/main.dev.dart --verbose'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to resolve this, turned out to be naming conventions.

my import looked like this:

```
import 'package:columbus/services/AppVersion/app_version_service.dart';
```

But the folder path was as follows:

```
columbus/services/appVersion/app_version_service.dart
```

Note the lower case A in appVersions, where in the import it is AppVersions.

MacOS file system is not case sensitive, where is Linux is!